# Why does iTunes API access work via JQuery but not XMLHttpRequest Object?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I can access the itunes API using JQuery. The following works perfect without a server.

```
$(function(){

    var apiURL = "https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=funk&media=music&callback=?";

    $.getJSON(apiURL,function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

I want to access it using the regular XMLHttpRequest object. I am curious how to make it work.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'https://itunes.apple.com/search term=funk&media=music&callback=?');
xhr.send();
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your URL has a callback in the query string, `getJSON` uses jsonp.
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/#jsonp

This loads the data in via a script tag rather than via XHR. JSONP is the only way to get that particular resource to load across domains, since `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` isn't set.